# How to make html ignore code that is part of text?

Tags: html

I need to include some codes in my html document

I've tried `<pre>` tag, but that didn't help.

How do I get this code into a document like text?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short Answer.

Encode your code using an online [HTML Encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/encode.aspx) and then put it inside `pre`

```
<pre>
    <%--your encoded code goes here--%>
</pre>
```

Long Answer.

The above will only help you to show your code. If you want proper highlighting for your code, Try something like **SyntaxHighlighter**

Link: [How to use SyntaxHighlighter.](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Sorry naveen, but in most cases the pre tag has css styles by default. So if you use this just to make html ignore your tags inside text, the whole block gets unwanted styling. I guess this causes downvotes.

Comment: I did, but the question is "How to make html ignore code that is part of text?". "part of text" means to me simple copy text. E.g.: "Hello world, I use the <div> tag often." Interpreted in this way, both of your answers don't give exactly the expected quick solutions to someone who googled after "ignore html tags in text".

Comment: pre tag with SyntaxHighlighter still requires escaping < to &lt;. The true escape free method is to use a TextArea (with out without SyntaxHighligther. SyntaxHighlighter works with TextArea.) The TextArea can display the text without any escaping, but it needs to be formatted so it doesn't look weird.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Example:

```
<div>
   Some Stuff
</div>
```

should be

```
&lt;div&gt;
   Some Stuff
&lt;/div&gt;
```

and it will render as the first one

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<pre>` tag. Each time you insert any texts within the `<pre>` tag it wont get parsed as html document. One caveat though, if you try to put an opening HTML tag inside the pre tag, you have to do it like this:

```
<pre>
     &lt;TEST>
            TEST!!
     &lt;/TEST>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people might crucify me not escaping my code. But this worked for me.

CSS

```
.tag:before{
content: '<'
}
.tag:after{
content: '>'
}
```

HTML

```
<pre>
<span class="tag">tag</span>
</pre>

<!--Instead of having to escaping all the character-->
&lt;tag&gt; &lt;&#47;tag&gt;

<!--Kinda interested to see why this is bad. I understand that not escaping  code can be dangerous b/c of SQL injections and all sort of BS but why is this  not a viable option-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
[encode](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii)

Example:

```
<br> -> encoded -> &lt;br&gt;

use &lt;br&gt; in your text
```

same answer as Ibu but maybe you want a fast way to encode your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xmp` tag. It is easier and quicker than using an HTML encoder. Example:

```html
<h1>This is a heading.</h1>
<p>This is a pharagraph</p>
<xmp>
<h1>This is a heading.</h1>
<p>This is a pharagraph</p>
</xmp>
```

Comment: You should not use it in 2020. `xmp` has been deprecated since HTML 3.2 (published in 1997).

Comment: @zsolt But it still is an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags. The `<pre>` tag retains the formatting , and the `<code>` tag outputs in monospaced font.  Wrap the `<code>` tag in `<pre>` tag, and paste whatever block of code in the `<code>` elements body.  This will output like the following:

`<pre>
<code>
   function(){ 
      var myVar = "This is code";
      return myVar;
   }
</code>
</pre>`

Comment: This won't work for HTML tags.  The tags themselves have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

To not escape any characters at all, you can use a textarea:

```css
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;

  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>In order to show a bullet point in html use the li tags:</div>
<div>
  <textarea readonly><li>Hello</li></textarea>
</div>
<div>And this is what it will look like:</div>
<li>Hello</li>
```

Run the snippet and notice the <li> and </li> tags render verbatim rather than being converted to a bullet.

Now why do we need the CSS and the extra HTML tags and attributes?

The CSS removes all the styling from textarea since the textarea will typically include styling for borders, resize gripper, and will use "input" style fonts. The textarea tag needs the "readonly" attribute so users can't edit it. The extra div tag around the textarea makes the textarea insert more correctly into the document flow.

It has some extra steps and it changes the DOM considerably but if you really need to show text strictly without escaping any characters at all for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to display a piece of code so you can just use https://highlightjs.org/

1. include this in your web page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.6.0/build/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.6.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
```

then add the `<pre><code>` tags to wrap your escaped piece of code
you can use https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html

```html
<pre>
  <code class="language-html">
     &lt;h1&gt;this is my HTML code&lt;/h1&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

or for CSS code

```html
<pre>
  <code class="language-css">
     input { caret-color: red;}
  </code>
</pre>
```

doc here https://highlightjs.org/usage/